# What are some good resources (that you recommend) for improving coding style?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm wondering if any experienced Java programmers could point out a few resources (can be websites, books, ebooks, videos, etc) that show a programmer good programming styles.

I look at my code and compare it to some example source online and mine just looks bloated, poorly formatted, and just not as readable as other's code. I know each programmer has their own style, but I would like to kick any bad programming habits that I've picked up. I would like my code to be read to an individual who has never touched the source before.

I know there are a lot of resources out there, but I don't know what the name of the topic is to be honest. (good programming structure? good programming conventions?)

I would like if there are some books I could pick up and read on the topic.

I appreciate any and all answers.

Comment: Running your code through PMD and Checkstyle is a good start (but is far from being sufficient)

Comment: Well the first step is recognizing the potential for improvements! A general advice would be to always think about how would someone who has never seen this code read this (or yourself a few months from now when you've forgotten about ti). "Is it readable?"

Comment: @JBNizet I had to search what PMD and Checkstyle were. Thanks for the information, I'll be getting both of them. Looks like a good starting point!

Comment: Read other people's code. Code that looks ugly and bloated to beginners often is battle-hardened, working, all catches thought through code (code in tutorials generally isn't, because that's usually not the point the author wants to make in it). With the advance of OpenSource there are lots of projects to chose from, although obviously you should try one with a good reputation in that regard. I fear the question isn't right for SO though - maybe programmers.

Comment: @Pulsar That is exactly my issue. I don't think my code would be readable to others. Or it would at the very least, be a bit of work to understand whats happening. That's where I'm wanting to improve :)

Comment: @Voo Sorry, fairly new here. Perhaps I'll ask at programmers. Thanks for letting me know. I have checked into some other people's code, however a lot of open source seems a bit advanced for what my prior knowledge is. I'm still learning, but I want to learn the proper ways rather than learn improper coding and having to fix it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) is an excellent book.

Comment: Looks like it got good reviews and may be worth looking into. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Code complete](http://cc2e.com/) (2nd Edition).

> Code Complete is a software
>   development book, written by Steve
>   McConnell and published by Microsoft
>   Press, urging developers to get past
>   code and fix programming and the "big
>   design up front" waterfall model. It
>   is also a compendium of software
>   construction techniques, from naming
>   variables to deciding when to write a
>   subroutine.

Comment: This too looks like it will be a good read. Thank you for the suggestion.